# Why can we say that `This is a transitive operation'?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am reading the textbook in algebra and it says that

> Define left multiplication action of a group on itself :
> $$
> G\times G\to G, g\cdot x=gx,\text{ for }g, x \in G
> $$
> Why does the author say `This is a transitive operation'?

The definition of transitive operation is that the orbit of this action is just one. But for the following example: for $G=Z/2Z=\{-1,+1\}$ and $S=R$, define

$$
\pi: G\times S \to S, (g,x):=x \mbox { if } g=1, (g,x):=-x \mbox { if } g=-1
$$

There are lots of orbits:
$$
O_0=\{0\}, O_2=\{2, -2\}
$$

Comment: Your example is not the action of a group on itself, but rather, on a different group.

Answer (score 1):

Not all actions are transitive. But the left multiplication action on a group by itself is(determine the orbit of $e$, identity element of $G$).

Comment: No...I am still confused. So why the orbits is just one?

Comment: Orbit of $e$, $O_e=\{g \cdot e=g\mid g\in G\}=G$

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ acts on a set $X$, then the orbit of $x\in X$ is $\mathcal O_x = \{g.x: g\in G\}$. The action is said to be *transitive* if $X = \mathcal O_x$ for any (and hence all) $x \in X$. If you take $X=G$ and the action map
$$
a\colon G\times X = G\times G \to X=G, \quad a(g,h) = gh,
$$
then $a$ is called the (left) action of $G$ on itself, and it is transitive because if $g_1,g_2 \in G$ are an arbitrary pair of elements of $G$, then $a(g_2 g_1^{-1},g_1) = g_2$.

In your example, you take $G = \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \cong \{\pm 1\}$, and let $G$ act on "$S=R$" which I think means the real numbers $\mathbb R$. The action of $G = \{\pm 1\}$ is just via scalar multiplication. This $G$-action does indeed have many orbits -- if $x\in \mathbb R$ then the orbit of $x$ is $\{x,-x\}$, and this has two elements when $x\neq 0$ and one element if $x=0$.

Now $G=\{\pm 1\} \subseteq \mathbb R$ can be viewed as a subset of $\mathbb R$, and indeed it is a single orbit of the $G$-action on $\mathbb R$, so the assertion that $G$ is a transitive $G$-set is completely consistent with the example $G = \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ and $S = \mathbb R$. Can you try to articulate what it was about this example that troubled you?